# Aquamacs error code 127; LaTeX: problems after [0] pages error

Tags: latex, aquamacs

I have a new `macbook pro (OSX 10.10)` and I installed `Aquamacs  3.2 GNU Emacs 24.4.51.2`
I have used aquamacs on an old machine for over a year with few problems.

The installation seemed simple and straightforward, basically double click the dmg file and move the icon to Applications.

MESSAGES WHILE STARTING UP ACQAMACS:

> Loading prestart plugin files ... ... done. Wrote
>   /Users/greggold/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Packages/.nosearch
>   Shell: /bin/bash Loading /Users/greggold/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs
>   Emacs/Recent Files.el (source)...done Cleaning up the recentf
>   list...done (0 removed) 16 environment variables imported from login
>   shell (/bin/bash). Loading /Volumes/Aquamacs
>   Emacs/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/aquamacs/edit-modes/auctex.el
>   (source)...done Loading plugins ... Loading /Volumes/Aquamacs
>   Emacs/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/aquamacs/site-start.el
>   (source)...done ... done. Loading `custom-file' failed. Loading
>   /Users/greggold/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Preferences.el
>   (source)...done Mark set one-buffer-one-frame-mode disabled. Mark set
>   [26 times] Loading /Users/greggold/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs
>   Emacs/frame-positions.el (source)...done file-error: (Opening
>   directory no such file or directory
>   /Users/greggold/Library/Logs/CrashReporter) Mark set [5 times]
>
> MY USER FILE (clump_present4.tex) WAS THEN LOADED Mark set [3 times]
>   Auto-saving...done Auto-saving...done Mark set No connection file
>   "/var/folders/q_/v6d8z7t96x911lskqblhg_680000gn/T/emacs501/server"
>   Automatic display of crossref information was turned on Applying style
>   hooks... Loading /Volumes/Aquamacs
>   Emacs/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/aquamacs/edit-modes/auctex/style/article.elc...done
>   Loading /Volumes/Aquamacs
>   Emacs/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/aquamacs/edit-modes/auctex/style/graphicx.elc...done
>   Loading /Volumes/Aquamacs
>   Emacs/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/aquamacs/edit-modes/auctex/style/amssymb.elc...done
>   Loading /Volumes/Aquamacs
>   Emacs/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/aquamacs/edit-modes/auctex/style/amsmath.elc...done
>   Loading /Volumes/Aquamacs
>   Emacs/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/aquamacs/edit-modes/auctex/style/amstext.elc...done
>   Loading /Volumes/Aquamacs
>   Emacs/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/aquamacs/edit-modes/auctex/style/amsbsy.elc...done
>   Loading /Volumes/Aquamacs
>   Emacs/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/aquamacs/edit-modes/auctex/style/amsopn.elc...done
>   Loading /Volumes/Aquamacs
>   Emacs/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/aquamacs/edit-modes/auctex/style/fancyhdr.elc...done
>   Applying style hooks... done  is undefined [3 times]
>
> CLICK ON LATEX (compile command)  Type `^C ^L' to display results of
>   compilation. LaTeX: problems after [0] pages
>
> TeX Output exited abnormally with code 127 at Mon Jan  5 17:09:56
>   Running `LaTeX' on`clump_present4' with ``pdflatex  --synctex=1
>   -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" clump_present4.tex'' /bin/sh: pdflatex: command not found TeX Output exited abnormally with code 127
>   at Mon Jan  5 17:09:56 I tried to run pdflatex from a terminal but it
>   was not found; and locate pdflatex only found a pdf file bash-3.2$
>   locate pdflatex
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/tests/baseline_images/test_backend_pgf/pgf_pdflatex.pdf
>   bash-3.2$

Any advice would be much appeciated

Answer (score 0):

I am using this on yosemite and am not having any problems.  I would suggest that you go to the aquamacs.org site go into the developers area. There was a problem unrelated to what you are showing with yosemite and the developer there was very helpful in fixing it. I would email him he probably can from your info tell you what is going on.

Before doing that try the development version that is on that page just in case that fixes it for you. That is the one I ended up using and I don't know if they have forced it back into the main download yet.

Also they have all the old email listing of problems that you may want to troll through. I use it for latex and find it is excellent. Particularly when teamed with skim.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered Aquamacs requires that latex be installed separately, if you want the latex button to compile; latex is not included in Aquamacs. This was so obvious to (almost) everyone that the point is not made in the installation instructions (or anything I could find). I installed the Mac Tex package and that solved the problem.